# JavaScript Scoping and Closure Syntax

Tags: javascript, html, css, scoping

I am having problems with scoping and closure in a JavaScript snippet. I am trying to update both the `class` and `onclick` properties of a button. Basically this should toggle between "High" and "Low". I could get the function to execute without trying to rescope the parameters but it was not successfully updating the properties. So, I tried to rescope it to the code below and I am now getting an error that `channel` is not defined. Can anyone help me out with the syntax here? I need the inner function to be able to evaluate both channel and value.

I know the code as provided will not work because of the asynchronous callback. I just can't seem to get the scoping syntax correct for the `onreadystatechange` function. Please let me know if I can provide any more clarification for the problem I am having. Thanks.

```js
function setDio(channel, value) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = (function(channel,value) { return function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4)
  {
   if (this.status === 200) {
    document.getElementById('ok-msg').innerHTML = 'Digital Output successfully set to '+value+'.';
    document.getElementById('ok-alert').style.display = 'block';
    if(value===1)
    {
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-high').class = 'ibradioactive';
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-low').class = 'ibradioinactive';
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-low').onclick = function(){ setDio(channel,0);};;
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-high').onclick = function(){} ;;
    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-high').class = 'ibradioinactive';
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-low').class = 'ibradioactive';
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-high').onclick = function(){ setDio(channel,1);};;
     document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-low').onclick = function(){} ;;
    }
   }
   else
   {
    document.getElementById('error-msg').innerHTML = 'Digital Output set failed ('+ this.status +'): '+this.responseText;
    document.getElementById('error-alert').style.display = 'block';
   }
        }
    };})(channel,value);
    xmlhttp.open('POST', '/dio/' + channel, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send('dio-value=' + value);
}
```

```css
.alert,.ok-alert,.error-alert,.info-alert,.warning-alert {
font-family:arial;
font-weight:700;
color:#FFF;
margin-bottom:15px;
border-radius:20px;
padding:20px;
display:none;
}

.ok-alert {
background-color:#4CAF50;
}

.error-alert {
background-color:#f44336;
}

.info-alert {
background-color:#2196F3;
}

.warning-alert {
background-color:#ff9800;
}

.alert-close {
margin-left:15px;
color:#FFF;
font-weight:700;
float:right;
font-size:22px;
line-height:20px;
cursor:pointer;
transition:.3s;
}

.inner-group {
display:inline-block;
border:0 solid #000;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:700;
font-size:12pt;
background:#ccc;
border-radius:15px;
vertical-align:text-top;
box-shadow:4px 4px 10px #66a;
margin:10px;
padding:10px 4px;
transition:1s;
}
.ibradioactive {
background:#11AF11;
}

.ibradioactive span {
color:#fff;
}

.ibradioinactive span {
color:#000;
}

.ibradioinactive {
background:#ddd;
}

.ibradioinactive:hover {
background-color:#acf;
}

.ibradio,.ibradioactive,.ibradioinactive {
width:50px;
height:50px;
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 2px #000;
font-weight:700;
color:#000;
border-radius:40px;
border:1px solid #999;
margin:10px 10px 10px 20px;
padding:5px;
}
label {
display:inline-block;
width:125px;
padding:3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="error-alert" class="error-alert">
  <span class="alert-close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <span id="error-msg">This is an error alert box.</span>
</div>
<div id="ok-alert" class="ok-alert">
  <span class="alert-close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <span id="ok-msg">This is a success alert box.</span>
</div>
<div id="info-alert" class="info-alert">
  <span class="alert-close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <span id="info-msg">This is an info alert box.</span>
</div>
<div id="warning-alert" class="warning-alert">
  <span class="alert-close" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <span id="warning-msg">This is an warning alert box.</span>
</div>
<br />

<div class="inner-group" style="width:550px;">
<label class="l2">Digital I/O #1</label><br>
<label class="l2" style="width:175px">Mode: OUTPUT</label><br />
<label class="l2">New State:</label>
<button class ="ibradioactive" type="submit" id="dio1-high" name="dio1-high" onclick="setDio(1,1)"><span>HIGH</span></button>
<button class ="ibradioinactive" type="submit" id="dio1-low" name="dio1-low" onclick="setDio(1,0)"><span>LOW</span></button>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Here is a simplified version of my original code that wasn't working:

```js
function setDio(channel, value) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4)
    {
      if (this.status === 200) {
        if(value === 1)
        {
          document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-high').class = 'ibradioactive';
          document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-low').class = 'ibradioinactive';
        }
        else
        {
          document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-high').class = 'ibradioinactive';
          document.getElementById('dio'+channel+'-low').class = 'ibradioactive';
        }
      }
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open('POST', '/dio/' + channel, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send('dio-value=' + value);
}
```

Because it wasn't working, I tried re-scoping and adding closure to make sure that the function was evaluating the parameter values that were used at call time versus picking up default values.

The classes were not changing as expected and, in fact, the asynchronous request was not actually being picked up by the server. So, can anyone see why this particular function would not work properly? I have similar functions that are just updating simple `innerHTML` values successfully. Changing the class, however, does not seem to be working.

EDIT 2:

So, I discovered part of my problem. The reason the class was not changing is that I was trying to set the `class` with text instead of an object. Changing to `className` seems to have cleared that up. I also went back to not using any extra closure scoping and it may be working properly now. Still doing testing to verify all the changes.

Comment: Please boil down your code to a few dozen lines.

Comment: I second torazaburo's comment. HTML and CSS seems to be unnecessary and if your problem is about scopes the `document.getElementById()` call are not necessary either. Value observations from the debugger or console outputs should suffice. Please add an _expected_ and _actual_ result description. And please reduce the indentation.

Comment: Not sure why the code snippet put such large indentations. I think it converted to tabs for some reason. I included everything because the function should be changing CSS style properties and they are not getting changed. I will simplify my code to just include the relevant JS to look at. Not quite following why you said `getElementById()` is not necessary. How else am I going to access the properties of the elements that need to be changed when the results of the request have been returned?

Comment: Looks like this problem didn't have anything to do with closure or scoping. I unnecessarily made the code more complex than it didn't to be based on some false assumptions. Code is all working great now. Thanks for all the input. Sometimes you just need to know that you are going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why there is need for explicit closure defined..

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  console.log(channel); // parent function parameter can still be accessed here.
}
```

Comment: Though you're right, this is rather a comment and as it's currently written the question is quite unclear since it lacks a clear problem description. Consider updating your question with _references (from MDN for example) added_ and update it according to question clarifications later.

Comment: So, I originally thought that was true as well, but things were not behaving properly. The right values were not getting accessed or changed. I will update my question with a before and after code changes.

Comment: Going back to no extra scoping or closure does indeed seem to be working. I may have cleared up the problem with changing the class attribute as well. Thanks for the suggestions and help.

Comment: All my code is working fine now. I was definitely going in the wrong direction and added unnecessary complication to the code. Your suggestions helped me re-evaluate my question to see that I was looking at the wrong problem. Thanks.